# Media queries : avoid inheritance?

Tags: iphone, css, web, media-queries

Good evening,

I have a website with a current css optimized for a desktop experience. I am working on an Iphone css, using IwebKit5 to provide a better user experience on the go.

I was using javascript, parsing the user agent to detect which css to use. I was looking for a way to avoid use of javascript, and discovered the media queries feature.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css"/>
```

This is what I tried, it works well on desktop (the Iphone css is ignored), but on Iphone I realized that both mobile.css and desktop.css are loaded, so I am trying to find a way to avoid that. What is the option to add in order to avoid this behavior ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're approaching this the wrong way.

Include `desktop.css` *first*, and let that be included unconditionally.

Then, inside `mobile.css`, add/override whatever properties you need to.

The vast majority of `desktop.css` should still be relevant on the iPhone - you should just be adjusting sizes/lengths and other such small tweaks on various elements inside `mobile.css`.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I have an issue when I want to add in the html an element exclusively for the iphone version. If I set it as "display : none" in the desktop.css and "display: inline" in the mobile.css, it doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: If you're including the desktop CSS first, and then the mobile CSS, and you have `#myDiv { display: none }` in the desktop CSS, and `#myDiv { display: inline }` in the mobile CSS, it *will work*. If it doesn't, then you're doing something else wrong. Perhaps you want `display: block` instead of `display: inline`? What does `"it doesn't seem to work"` mean?

Comment: The content was still hidden ... Anyway, you're right, it work by setting the display property to block. Thanks a lot !